# Mysql 8.0.28 replication with xtrabackup on k8s

Tags: mysql, kubernetes, replication

**Problem**

I want to do mysql 8.0.28 replication with xtrabackup on k8s.
Based on k8s official example which is working fine(I will talk about it later in this post), I created k8s cluster for mysql 8.0.28 replication (Note mysql is 5.7 in the official example.) but does not work. My yaml file is

```
apiVersion: storage.k8s.io/v1
kind: StorageClass
metadata:
  name: mysql-sc
provisioner: kubernetes.io/no-provisioner
volumeBindingMode: WaitForFirstConsumer
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: mysql-pv
spec:
  capacity:
    storage: 5Gi
  volumeMode: Filesystem
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  storageClassName: mysql-sc
  local:
    path: /tmp
  nodeAffinity:
    required:
      nodeSelectorTerms:
      - matchExpressions:
        - key: kubernetes.io/hostname
          operator: In
          values:
          - controlplane
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: mysql-pv-2
spec:
  capacity:
    storage: 5Gi
  volumeMode: Filesystem
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  storageClassName: mysql-sc
  local:
    path: /tmp
  nodeAffinity:
    required:
      nodeSelectorTerms:
      - matchExpressions:
        - key: kubernetes.io/hostname
          operator: In
          values:
          - node01
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: mysql
  labels:
    app: mysql
    app.kubernetes.io/name: mysql
data:
  my.cnf: |
    [mysqld]
    !includedir /etc/mysql/conf.d/
  primary.cnf: |
    # Apply this config only on the primary.
    [mysqld]
    log-bin
    gtid_mode=ON
    enforce_gtid_consistency=ON
  replica.cnf: |
    # Apply this config only on replicas.
    [mysqld]
    gtid_mode=ON
    enforce_gtid_consistency=ON
    super-read-only
    log_bin=OFF
---
# Headless service for stable DNS entries of StatefulSet members.
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: mysql
  labels:
    app: mysql
    app.kubernetes.io/name: mysql
spec:
  ports:
  - name: mysql
    port: 3306
  clusterIP: None
  selector:
    app: mysql
---
# Client service for connecting to any MySQL instance for reads.
# For writes, you must instead connect to the primary: mysql-0.mysql.
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: mysql-read
  labels:
    app: mysql
    app.kubernetes.io/name: mysql
    readonly: "true"
spec:
  ports:
  - name: mysql
    port: 3306
  selector:
    app: mysql
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: StatefulSet
metadata:
  name: mysql
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: mysql
      app.kubernetes.io/name: mysql
  serviceName: mysql
  replicas: 2
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: mysql
        app.kubernetes.io/name: mysql
    spec:
      initContainers:
      - name: init-mysql
        image: mysql:8.0.28
        command:
        - bash
        - "-c"
        - |
          set -ex
          # Generate mysql server-id from pod ordinal index.
          [[ `uname -n` =~ -([0-9]+)$ ]] || exit 1
          ordinal=${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
          echo [mysqld] > /mnt/conf.d/server-id.cnf
          # Add an offset to avoid reserved server-id=0 value.
          echo server-id=$((100 + $ordinal)) >> /mnt/conf.d/server-id.cnf
          # Copy my.cnf file from config-map to conf-2 volume(emptyDir).
          cp /mnt/config-map/my.cnf /mnt/conf-2/
          # Copy appropriate conf.d files from config-map to emptyDir.
          if [[ $ordinal -eq 0 ]]; then
            cp /mnt/config-map/primary.cnf /mnt/conf.d/
          else
            cp /mnt/config-map/replica.cnf /mnt/conf.d/
          fi          
        volumeMounts:
        - name: conf
          mountPath: /mnt/conf.d
        - name: conf-2
          mountPath: /mnt/conf-2
        - name: config-map
          mountPath: /mnt/config-map
      - name: clone-mysql
        image: hiroaki2020/dtuj_xtrabackup:1.0
        securityContext:
          runAsUser: 0
          runAsGroup: 0
        command:
        - bash
        - "-c"
        - |
          set -ex
          # Skip the clone if data already exists.
          [[ -d /var/lib/mysql/mysql ]] && exit 0
          # Skip the clone on primary (ordinal index 0).
          [[ `uname -n` =~ -([0-9]+)$ ]] || exit 1
          ordinal=${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
          [[ $ordinal -eq 0 ]] && exit 0
          # Clone data from previous peer.
          ncat --recv-only mysql-$(($ordinal-1)).mysql 3307 | xbstream -x -C /var/lib/mysql
          # Prepare the backup.
          xtrabackup --prepare --target-dir=/var/lib/mysql          
        volumeMounts:
        - name: data
          mountPath: /var/lib/mysql
          subPath: mysql
        - name: conf
          mountPath: /etc/mysql/conf.d
        - name: conf-2
          mountPath: /etc/mysql
      containers:
      - name: mysql
        image: mysql:8.0.28
        resources:
          limits:
            memory: 512Mi
            cpu: 500m
          requests:
            memory: 128Mi
            cpu: 100m
        env:
        - name: MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD
          value: "1"
        ports:
        - name: mysql
          containerPort: 3306
        volumeMounts:
        - name: data
          mountPath: /var/lib/mysql
          subPath: mysql
        - name: conf
          mountPath: /etc/mysql/conf.d
        livenessProbe:
          exec:
            command: ["mysqladmin", "ping"]
          initialDelaySeconds: 30
          periodSeconds: 10
          timeoutSeconds: 5
        readinessProbe:
          exec:
            # Check we can execute queries over TCP (skip-networking is off).
            command: ["mysql", "-h", "127.0.0.1", "-e", "SELECT 1"]
          initialDelaySeconds: 5
          periodSeconds: 2
          timeoutSeconds: 1
      - name: xtrabackup
        image: hiroaki2020/dtuj_xtrabackup:1.0
        securityContext:
          runAsUser: 0
          runAsGroup: 0
        ports:
        - name: xtrabackup
          containerPort: 3307
        command:
        - bash
        - "-c"
        - |
          set -ex
          cd /var/lib/mysql

          # Determine binlog position of cloned data, if any.
          if [[ -f xtrabackup_slave_info && "x$(<xtrabackup_slave_info)" != "x" ]]; then
            # XtraBackup already generated a partial "CHANGE MASTER TO" query
            # because we're cloning from an existing replica. (Need to remove the tailing semicolon!)
            cat xtrabackup_slave_info | sed -E 's/;$//g' > change_master_to.sql.in
            # Ignore xtrabackup_binlog_info in this case (it's useless).
            rm -f xtrabackup_slave_info xtrabackup_binlog_info
          elif [[ -f xtrabackup_binlog_info ]]; then
            # We're cloning directly from primary. Parse binlog position.
            [[ `cat xtrabackup_binlog_info` =~ ^([^.]*\.[0-9]+)[[:space:]]+([0-9]+) ]] || exit 1
            rm -f xtrabackup_binlog_info xtrabackup_slave_info
            echo "CHANGE MASTER TO MASTER_LOG_FILE='${BASH_REMATCH[1]}',\
                  MASTER_LOG_POS=${BASH_REMATCH[2]}" > change_master_to.sql.in
          fi

          # Check if we need to complete a clone by starting replication.
          if [[ -f change_master_to.sql.in ]]; then
            echo "Waiting for mysqld to be ready (accepting connections)"
            until mysql -h 127.0.0.1 -e "SELECT 1"; do sleep 1; done

            echo "Initializing replication from clone position"
            mysql -h 127.0.0.1 \
                  -e "$(<change_master_to.sql.in), \
                          MASTER_HOST='mysql-0.mysql', \
                          MASTER_USER='root', \
                          MASTER_PASSWORD='', \
                          MASTER_CONNECT_RETRY=10; \
                        START SLAVE;" || exit 1
            # In case of container restart, attempt this at-most-once.
            mv change_master_to.sql.in change_master_to.sql.orig
          fi

          # Start a server to send backups when requested by peers.
          exec ncat --listen --keep-open --send-only --max-conns=1 3307 -c \
            "xtrabackup --backup --slave-info --stream=xbstream --host=127.0.0.1 --user=root"          
        volumeMounts:
        - name: data
          mountPath: /var/lib/mysql
          subPath: mysql
        - name: conf
          mountPath: /etc/mysql/conf.d
        - name: conf-2
          mountPath: /etc/mysql
        resources:
          limits:
            cpu: 500m
            memory: 512Mi
          requests:
            cpu: 100m
            memory: 100Mi
      volumes:
      - name: conf
        emptyDir: {}
      - name: conf-2
        emptyDir: {}
      - name: config-map
        configMap:
          name: mysql
  volumeClaimTemplates:
  - metadata:
      name: data
    spec:
      accessModes: ["ReadWriteOnce"]
      storageClassName: mysql-sc
      resources:
        requests:
          storage: 5Gi
```

In the yaml file above, I changed mysql image version and use my original image called "hiroaki2020/dtuj_xtrabackup:1.0" based on Dockerfile below.

```
FROM percona/percona-xtrabackup:8.0.28
LABEL maintainer="hiroaki"

RUN microdnf update && \
    rm -rf /var/cache/yum && \
    microdnf -y install nmap-ncat shadow-utils && \
    groupadd --system -g 27 mysql && \
    useradd --system -s /usr/bin/false -g mysql -u 27 -c mysql --no-create-home --home-dir /nonexistent mysql && \
    microdnf -y remove shadow-utils && \
    microdnf clean all

USER mysql
```

This image is based on xtrabackup image with its version corresponding to the one of mysql (=8.0.28). I also added ncat cmd and change user to mysql but to make it simple, change it back to root in k8s manifest yaml file by setting securityContext.

I applied the k8s manifest file above in killercoda k8s playground but when the 2nd mysql pod(=mysql-1) is starting, more exactly, when clone-mysql container is working in the 2nd pod, xtrabackup container in the 1st mysql pod get error like

```
Ncat: assertion failed: count <= INT_MAX QUITTING.
```

How can I fix this?

**k8s official example which works fine**

As I said, manifest file above is based on [k8s official example](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/run-application/run-replicated-stateful-application/#before-you-begin). With this example, I successfully ran mysql replication containers on k8s but mysql version is 5.7. Comparison may help solve problem so I provide simple steps of this example.

Step 1

Open killercoda k8s playground and login. There is the link to it in the k8s official example link above. This official example may work with other playgrounds or k8s on local PC such as minikube but I am not sure.

Step 2

```
vim k8s.yaml
```

and paste this.

```
apiVersion: storage.k8s.io/v1
kind: StorageClass
metadata:
  name: mysql-sc
provisioner: kubernetes.io/no-provisioner
volumeBindingMode: WaitForFirstConsumer
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: mysql-pv
spec:
  capacity:
    storage: 1Gi
  volumeMode: Filesystem
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  storageClassName: mysql-sc
  local:
    path: /tmp
  nodeAffinity:
    required:
      nodeSelectorTerms:
      - matchExpressions:
        - key: kubernetes.io/hostname
          operator: In
          values:
          - controlplane
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: mysql-pv-2
spec:
  capacity:
    storage: 1Gi
  volumeMode: Filesystem
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  storageClassName: mysql-sc
  local:
    path: /tmp
  nodeAffinity:
    required:
      nodeSelectorTerms:
      - matchExpressions:
        - key: kubernetes.io/hostname
          operator: In
          values:
          - node01
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: mysql
  labels:
    app: mysql
    app.kubernetes.io/name: mysql
data:
  primary.cnf: |
    # Apply this config only on the primary.
    [mysqld]
    log-bin    
  replica.cnf: |
    # Apply this config only on replicas.
    [mysqld]
    super-read-only    
---
# Headless service for stable DNS entries of StatefulSet members.
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: mysql
  labels:
    app: mysql
    app.kubernetes.io/name: mysql
spec:
  ports:
  - name: mysql
    port: 3306
  clusterIP: None
  selector:
    app: mysql
---
# Client service for connecting to any MySQL instance for reads.
# For writes, you must instead connect to the primary: mysql-0.mysql.
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: mysql-read
  labels:
    app: mysql
    app.kubernetes.io/name: mysql
    readonly: "true"
spec:
  ports:
  - name: mysql
    port: 3306
  selector:
    app: mysql
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: StatefulSet
metadata:
  name: mysql
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: mysql
      app.kubernetes.io/name: mysql
  serviceName: mysql
  replicas: 2
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: mysql
        app.kubernetes.io/name: mysql
    spec:
      initContainers:
      - name: init-mysql
        image: mysql:5.7
        command:
        - bash
        - "-c"
        - |
          set -ex
          # Generate mysql server-id from pod ordinal index.
          [[ `uname -n` =~ -([0-9]+)$ ]] || exit 1
          ordinal=${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
          echo [mysqld] > /mnt/conf.d/server-id.cnf
          # Add an offset to avoid reserved server-id=0 value.
          echo server-id=$((100 + $ordinal)) >> /mnt/conf.d/server-id.cnf
          # Copy appropriate conf.d files from config-map to emptyDir.
          if [[ $ordinal -eq 0 ]]; then
            cp /mnt/config-map/primary.cnf /mnt/conf.d/
          else
            cp /mnt/config-map/replica.cnf /mnt/conf.d/
          fi          
        volumeMounts:
        - name: conf
          mountPath: /mnt/conf.d
        - name: config-map
          mountPath: /mnt/config-map
      - name: clone-mysql
        image: gcr.io/google-samples/xtrabackup:1.0
        command:
        - bash
        - "-c"
        - |
          set -ex
          # Skip the clone if data already exists.
          [[ -d /var/lib/mysql/mysql ]] && exit 0
          # Skip the clone on primary (ordinal index 0).
          [[ `hostname` =~ -([0-9]+)$ ]] || exit 1
          ordinal=${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
          [[ $ordinal -eq 0 ]] && exit 0
          # Clone data from previous peer.
          ncat --recv-only mysql-$(($ordinal-1)).mysql 3307 | xbstream -x -C /var/lib/mysql
          # Prepare the backup.
          xtrabackup --prepare --target-dir=/var/lib/mysql          
        volumeMounts:
        - name: data
          mountPath: /var/lib/mysql
          subPath: mysql
        - name: conf
          mountPath: /etc/mysql/conf.d
      containers:
      - name: mysql
        image: mysql:5.7
        resources:
          limits:
            memory: 512Mi
            cpu: 300m
          requests:
            memory: 64Mi
            cpu: 50m
        env:
        - name: MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD
          value: "1"
        ports:
        - name: mysql
          containerPort: 3306
        volumeMounts:
        - name: data
          mountPath: /var/lib/mysql
          subPath: mysql
        - name: conf
          mountPath: /etc/mysql/conf.d
        livenessProbe:
          exec:
            command: ["mysqladmin", "ping"]
          initialDelaySeconds: 30
          periodSeconds: 10
          timeoutSeconds: 5
        readinessProbe:
          exec:
            # Check we can execute queries over TCP (skip-networking is off).
            command: ["mysql", "-h", "127.0.0.1", "-e", "SELECT 1"]
          initialDelaySeconds: 5
          periodSeconds: 2
          timeoutSeconds: 1
      - name: xtrabackup
        image: gcr.io/google-samples/xtrabackup:1.0
        ports:
        - name: xtrabackup
          containerPort: 3307
        command:
        - bash
        - "-c"
        - |
          set -ex
          cd /var/lib/mysql

          # Determine binlog position of cloned data, if any.
          if [[ -f xtrabackup_slave_info && "x$(<xtrabackup_slave_info)" != "x" ]]; then
            # XtraBackup already generated a partial "CHANGE MASTER TO" query
            # because we're cloning from an existing replica. (Need to remove the tailing semicolon!)
            cat xtrabackup_slave_info | sed -E 's/;$//g' > change_master_to.sql.in
            # Ignore xtrabackup_binlog_info in this case (it's useless).
            rm -f xtrabackup_slave_info xtrabackup_binlog_info
          elif [[ -f xtrabackup_binlog_info ]]; then
            # We're cloning directly from primary. Parse binlog position.
            [[ `cat xtrabackup_binlog_info` =~ ^(.*?)[[:space:]]+(.*?)$ ]] || exit 1
            rm -f xtrabackup_binlog_info xtrabackup_slave_info
            echo "CHANGE MASTER TO MASTER_LOG_FILE='${BASH_REMATCH[1]}',\
                  MASTER_LOG_POS=${BASH_REMATCH[2]}" > change_master_to.sql.in
          fi

          # Check if we need to complete a clone by starting replication.
          if [[ -f change_master_to.sql.in ]]; then
            echo "Waiting for mysqld to be ready (accepting connections)"
            until mysql -h 127.0.0.1 -e "SELECT 1"; do sleep 1; done

            echo "Initializing replication from clone position"
            mysql -h 127.0.0.1 \
                  -e "$(<change_master_to.sql.in), \
                          MASTER_HOST='mysql-0.mysql', \
                          MASTER_USER='root', \
                          MASTER_PASSWORD='', \
                          MASTER_CONNECT_RETRY=10; \
                        START SLAVE;" || exit 1
            # In case of container restart, attempt this at-most-once.
            mv change_master_to.sql.in change_master_to.sql.orig
          fi

          # Start a server to send backups when requested by peers.
          exec ncat --listen --keep-open --send-only --max-conns=1 3307 -c \
            "xtrabackup --backup --slave-info --stream=xbstream --host=127.0.0.1 --user=root"          
        volumeMounts:
        - name: data
          mountPath: /var/lib/mysql
          subPath: mysql
        - name: conf
          mountPath: /etc/mysql/conf.d
        resources:
          limits:
            cpu: 300m
            memory: 512Mi
          requests:
            cpu: 100m
            memory: 100Mi
      volumes:
      - name: conf
        emptyDir: {}
      - name: config-map
        configMap:
          name: mysql
  volumeClaimTemplates:
  - metadata:
      name: data
    spec:
      accessModes: ["ReadWriteOnce"]
      storageClassName: mysql-sc
      resources:
        requests:
          storage: 1Gi
```

I created local persistent volume and storage class and made a slight change to official example to get it work such as changing "hostname" cmd in script to "uname -n" and so on.

Step 3

run

```
kubectl apply -f k8s.yaml
```

Done. Wait until pods are ready and enter mysql container in mysql-0 pod and add some records with mysql client. You can see that data is properly replicated to replica server.

Answer (score 0):

I switched k8s platform from killercoda playground to minikube and I also changed ncat to the latest version and increased the resource allocation to mysql container and now mysql cluster works properly.